# Powershell PSReadLine : Get Key's for a given Function?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, psreadline

In `PSReadLine  2.2.2` for `PowerShell  7.2.11`, On Windows, you can also use the <kbd>Alt+?</kbd> key chord to show the function bound to the next key chord you enter.

Conversely, is there a key or PS command that will show keys for a given function?

For example, how can I accomplish:

**- Show all keys that are bound for the `BackwardDeleteChar` function?**

```
Key       Function           Description
---       --------           -----------
Backspace BackwardDeleteChar Delete the character before the cursor
Ctrl+h    BackwardDeleteChar Delete the character before the cursor
```

or 
**- Show all keys that are bound for the `MenuComplete` function>**

```
Key           Function            Description
---           --------            -----------
Ctrl+@        MenuComplete        Complete the input if there ...
Ctrl+Spacebar MenuComplete        Complete the input if there ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter the output from `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler`:

```
PS ~> Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler |Where-Object Function -eq MenuComplete

Completion functions
====================

Key           Function            Description
---           --------            -----------
Ctrl+@        MenuComplete        Complete the input if there ...
Ctrl+Spacebar MenuComplete        Complete the input if there ...
```